# Joining table variable and derived table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the query below `@processtable` is a table variable and temp is a derived table when I am trying to join them I am getting the following error:

> The column prefix 't' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

```
SELECT t.Order
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, temp.[DateTime], 101) AS [DateTime] 
       ,t.Status
       ,t.Domain
       ,t.Media
       ,t.Approved      
       ,t.CreatedBy     
FROM @ProcessTable t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Id),Order FROM OrderDetail OD WHERE  OD.Order = t.Order) temp
ON temp.Order = t.Order 
ORDER BY temp.[DateTime] DESC, Approved ASC
```

Comment: .. maybe it would be better to describe your data and explain what you want to get out of it.... because looking a your query this just wont work. – John Hartsock 1 min ago edit

Comment: @John- For the Order in @processtable ,I  need to get the datetime for that order from orderdetail table based on the max(ID) of the order i.e the latest DateTime for that order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost right...You dont need the where clause in side the derived table if your going to include it as one of the Join criteria.

```
SELECT     
  t.Order
  ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,temp.[DateTime],101) AS [DateTime] 
  ,t.Status
  ,t.Domain
  ,t.Media
  ,t.Approved     
  ,t.CreatedBy        
FROM @ProcessTable t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Id) AS MaxID,Order, Max([DateTime]) AS [DateTime] FROM OrderDetail OD Group By Order)  temp
  ON temp.Order = t.Order 
ORDER BY temp.[DateTime] DESC, Approved ASC
```

Comment: now it's giving me this error                                         No column was specified for column 1 of 'temp'.

Comment: @Pinu ...sorry yeah...when using agregates in Derived tables you must give it an alias....I will fix the answer

Comment: @Pinu.... finally include all the fields you need in your derived table.  Note you make use of temp.[DateTime] but I do not see it in the column list of your derived table.

Comment: @john- When I added DateTime to the select list , it gives me this error Column 'js.DateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Pinu... maybe it would be better to describe your data and explain what you want to get out of it.... because looking a your query this just wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT     t.Order
        ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,temp.[DateTime],101) AS [DateTime] 
        ,t.Status
        ,t.Domain
        ,t.Media
        ,t.Approved     
        ,t.CreatedBy        
    FROM @ProcessTable t
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(Id) AS LatestId, Order FROM OrderDetail OD GROUP BY Order)  temp
    ON temp.Order = t.Order 
    ORDER BY temp.[DateTime] DESC, Approved ASC
```

Note, I've remove the OD.Order = t.Order clause in the nested SELECT and added in a GROUP BY. The condition alongside that join (temp.Order = t.Order) does the filtering so doesn't need to be in the nested select - it was causing the error. Plus as you're using an aggregate function (MAX), you need the GROUP BY.

Also, I've given an alias for MAX(Id) to be returned as

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reference the t.Order in the subquery as such. You should simply rely on the join to handle that clause.

E.g. simply remove the OD.Order = t.Order and allow the join clause to handle it.